# Dot product of pandas vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to perform a simple calculation with pandas Series
Z(2000,1) . W^T(1,300) + B.T(1,300)

When I perform the dot product W.Z, I do not obtain a (2000, 300) matrix, but:

```
dot_product = Z.dot(W.T)
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I obtain a similar error when I perform the addition (the vector cannot be broadcasted). So Pandas consider that my vectors do not have the right shape, but I do not see where the culprit is. I have done this many times with Numpy without any trouble... I need to do it with Pandas to keep the indexes and obtained an indexed data frame.

Z is a frame of shape (2000, 1) with a time index:

```
                Z
2010-01-01 -0.135
2010-01-02  0.786
2010-01-03  0.099
2010-01-04 -0.332
2010-01-05 -0.097
```

W is an indexed frame of shape (300, 1):

```
        W
A1  0.344
B1  0.980
C1  0.099
D1  0.983
E1  0.873
```

B is a data frame with the same index and shape than W.

Comment: Just because a frame or series displays as a column, don't assume its numpy shape is (n,1).

Comment: The full error messages might help.  `dot` alignment messages are not similar to broadcasting ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [123]: S = pd.Series(np.arange(5))                                           
In [124]: W = pd.Series(np.arange(4))
```

Despite the column display, the Series is 1d:

```
In [125]: S.shape                                                               
Out[125]: (5,)
In [126]: S.dot(S)                                                              
Out[126]: 30                   # the usual vector dot
```

`S.dot(W)` would give a mismatch error because of different sizes

As with a 1d array, transpose does nothing:

```
In [127]: S.T.shape                                                               
Out[127]: (5,)
In [128]: S.T                                                                   
Out[128]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Indexing with `newaxis` produces an array with the added dimension:

```
In [134]: S[:,None]                                                             
Out[134]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
In [135]: S[:,None]*W[None,:]    # (5,1) (1,4) broadcasting                                               
Out[135]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12]])
```

and `dot` does the same thing.

`S[:,None]*W.to_numpy()` also works, but `S[:,None]*W` doesn't, showing that `pandas` does not handle `broadcasting` in the same way.  The traceback shows `pandas` does dispatch to the `numpy.ufunc`, but with its own wrapper.

Comment: I double checked the dimensionnality and it was not the issue. I indeed works with (n,p) arrays, and not (n,) arrays. In the end, I converted my data to numpy arrays, performed the calculation with numpy, then assigned the results to a new pandas data frame. This is not fully satisfying, but it works.